# Python store list from socket

Tags: python, list, increment

I'm facing a problem with my script:
I would like to store a string inside a list and increment this list with these strings.The string is retrieved from a server response.

This could be resumed like this in Python:

```
import socket
from socket import *

host = "10.0.0.23",445
def Test(host):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(host)  
    s.settimeout(30) 
    string ="Test"
    s.send(string)
    data = s.recv(2048)
    StringToStore = data[0:5]#Important: Values returned are random.
    return StringToStore

def ListIncrement(T):
    for x in range(5):  
        ListStr = Test(host)
    ListValue = list(ListStr)
    return ListValue

Testing = ListIncrement(Test)
print "Testing if ListIncrement returned a list of 5 differents strings :", Testing
```

This is clearly not working for some reasons i can't figure, but what I would like ListIncrement(T) to return is an array like this :

```
['1234','4321','3214','2314','4322']
```

Thanks much in advance !

Comment: *How* is it not working? (It's not "clear", especially since we can't reproduce the problem without variables like `AF_INET`, `SOCK_STREAM` and `buffer0`)

Comment: @DavidRobinson not to mention `T` and `host`

Comment: Also, your code is very confusing. You are passing a function `Test` into `ListIncrement`, but never using it (instead just using `Test` directly in the function). `Test` takes a variable `host`, but you never define `host` in this snippet. Also, the loop `for x in range(5): ListStr = Test(host)` will never create a list of 5 elements- it will just keep reassigning the value of `ListStr`. Are you new to Python?

Comment: Are you looking for the `.append()` method of a list?

Comment: (Adding the import statements doesn't make this any more reproducible)

Comment: @user1473508: The edit doesn't solve the issues with the question. Most notably, you don't explain *how* it's not working (and it's still not reproducible without variables like `AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM`). If you explained what you were getting instead of the expected output it would let us fix it (though I think my answer below will probably solve it).

Comment: Maybe consider updating the title of this question?  It really doesn't have anything to do with sockets, ultimately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to do something like:

```
    ListValue = []
    for x in range(5):  
        ListValue.append(Test(host))
    return ListValue
```

This could also be done as a list comprehension:

```
return [Test(host) for x in range(5)]
```